# Changing date formats

Tags: java, date, parsing, time, simpledateformat

I have the following code:

```
// OLD DATE
String date = "Mon, 06/07";

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
String strDate = date.substring(date.length() - 5);
Date dateOld;
try {
    dateOld = df.parse(strDate);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String dateStr = df.format(dateOld);
MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse(dateStr, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd"));
ZonedDateTime dateNew = ZonedDateTime.now().with(monthDay);

// NEW DATE
System.out.println(dateNew.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T00:00:00Z'")));
```

Basically what I am trying to do is change `Mon, 06/07` format to this format `2021-06-07T00:00:00Z`.

What I have works, but it is really terrible. What would be a better way of doing it?

Comment: Use a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the value to a `LocalDate`, then use a new `DateTimeFormatter` to format it to your desired result

Comment: You are right, that code is not good. First of all you should not use the old and troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes and you should not mix old and modern. Just stick to java.time, the modern Java date and time API to which `MonthDay`, `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZonedDateTime` belong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little tricky as you need to make some assumptions

- The year, as it's not specified in the original format
- TimeZone, as it's not specified at all (the final output seems to point to UTC)

The first thing your need to do, is parse the `String` input into a `LocalDate` (you could just go straight to `ZonedDate`, but this is where I started)

```
String date = "Mon, 06/07";
DateTimeFormatter parseFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("E, M/d")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, 2021)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);

LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, parseFormatter);
```

Then you need to convert that to `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime ldt = ld.atStartOfDay();
```

And then, to a `ZonedDateTime`.  Here' I've assumed UTC

```
//ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
//ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone(zoneId);
OffsetDateTime zdt = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

And finally, format the result to your desired format

```
String formatted = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Which, for me, prints...

```
2021-06-07T00:00:00Z
```

A lot of time and effort has gone into the new Date/Time APIs and you should make the time to try and learn them as best you can (I'm pretty rusty, but with a little tinkering, got to a result)

Maybe start with [Date/Time trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html)

Comment: Hey, quick question. What should be my adjustment in case the `date` has a word in the beginning instead of a month? For an example - `Tomorrow, 06/08`. Keeping it the way it is leads to `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Tomorrow, 06/08' could not be parsed at index 0`.

Comment: "Tomorrow" isn't a format that the `DateTimeFormatter` uses, so you'll need to make some kind of work around to adjust for it. You should check the JavaDocs for [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see what format specifiers it does support

Answer (score 1):

A solution use `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MM/dd", Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date oldDate = sdf.parse("Mon, 06/07");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int savedYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        if (oldDate != null) {
            calendar.setTime(oldDate);
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, savedYear);
            sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T00:00:00Z'");
            System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Since it's 2021 and `Calendar` and `Date` are effectively considered deprecated, if not obsolete, I'd avoid propagating their use in favour of the date/time APIs, as those APIs were replaced for (good) reasons